# Neural network not training

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to set up a custom neural network, but when I train it, it doesn't train : the training process makes 0 iterations! I don't get any errors though, just 0 iterations, and I have no idea why. (The architecture might seem odd to you, it is supposed to be a custom PNN. But before we can even discuss if it makes sense or not, I would like to be able to train it...)

Here is the code

```
  net = network;
  net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';
  net.performFcn = 'mse';
  net.numInputs = 1;
  net.numLayers = (2*nbclasses)+1; % (one pattern layer + one summation layer per class) + competition layer
  net.inputConnect(1:nbclasses,:) = 1; % connects the input to all pattern layers

    for i = 1:nbclasses % Connect the pattern layers to their corresponding summation layers
        net.layerConnect(i+nbclasses,i) = 1;
        net.layers{i}.size = size(tr_feature,1);
        net.layers{i}.transferFcn = 'radbas';
    end

    for i = (nbclasses+1):(nbclasses*2) % Connect all summation layers to the competition layer
        net.layers{i}.size = 1;
        net.layerConnect(net.numLayers,i) = 1;
    end

    net.layers{net.numLayers}.transferFcn = 'compet';    
    net.outputConnect(1,end) = 1;
    net.view;
    [net, tr] = train(net,tr_feature',tr_true');
    % tr_feature is a 800x2 data matrix, tr_true is the 800x1 corresponding labels
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you define `nbclasses`?

Comment: Earlier in some other part of the code which I skipped here. I'm pretty sure it has no incidence on the problem. :)

Comment: `1:[]` or `1:0` or `1:-20` all produce `Empty matrix: 1-by-0`. I suggest to set a conditional breakpoint `isempty(nbclasses) || nbclasses < 1` and run the code.

Comment: I checked and as I thought, nbclass is not empty nor zero. For my test case it is 2. Actually if it was 0 the network wouldn't have the desired structure ; but as net.view shows, the structure is correct. That's why I was pretty sure that the issue didn't come from here : nbclass is straightforwardly initialized ans the structure of the net is correct.

Comment: By *"training process makes 0 iterations"* you refer to `train(...)` or any of the loops? If the former, then you have not provided a MWE (minimum working example) that reproduces the issue, making it impossible (at least for me) to guess what goes wrong.